# Evaluate the sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!(n^4+n^2+1)}.$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sum to evaluate is:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n! \, (n^4+n^2+1)}$$

As for what I've tried:

- It is obvious that the $n$-th element converges to $0$
- If we take $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$$ and compare it to the sum we might get something but I hit a wall trying to do it.

Comment: "but I hit a wall trying to do it."  Here is a tip for good question-asking (in life, but in particular on math.SE): if you say "I tried X and it didn't work," that provides almost nothing constructive for someone to respond.  If you say, "*Here is my attempt to do X*, and this is where I got stuck" it provides the person helping you with actual information and lots of avenues to assist.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/794272/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3339016/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1574311/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D0%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7D%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn!%20%5C%2C%20(n%5E4%2Bn%5E2%2B1)%7D%24)

Answer (score 1):

Factor $(n^4 + n^2 +1) = (1 - n + n^2)(1 + n + n^2)$, break apart, note that $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} = e$, perform separate summations to find your answer is:  $\frac{e}{2}$.

(I later found this is closely related to [this solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/794272/how-to-find-the-sum-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1nn4n21), where the 1 comes from not having the $n=0$ term in the summation.)

Comment: Isn't the answer $(e-2)/2$?

Comment: I get $e/2$....